# Why the script coloring only some objects with a Renderer component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
//Adapted from Unity3DCollege YouTube Video Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdDrY8Mc2lU
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class CustomHierarchy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, 2);
    public static Color gameObjectFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabOrgFontColor = Color.black;
    public static Color prefabModFontColor = Color.white;
    public static Color inActiveColor = new Color(0.01f, 0.4f, 0.25f);
    static CustomHierarchy()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI;
    }
    private static void HandleHierarchyWindowItemOnGUI(int instanceID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Color fontColor = gameObjectFontColor;
        Color backgroundColor = new Color(.76f, .76f, .76f);
        FontStyle styleFont = FontStyle.Normal;
        var obj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID);
        GameObject gameObj = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as GameObject;
        if (Selection.instanceIDs.Contains(instanceID))
        {
            backgroundColor = new Color(0.24f, 0.48f, 0.90f);
        }
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(obj);
            if (gameObj.activeInHierarchy == false)
            {
                backgroundColor = inActiveColor;
            }

            if(gameObj.GetComponent<Renderer>() == true)
            {
                fontColor = Color.yellow;
            }

            if (prefabType == PrefabType.PrefabInstance)
            {
                styleFont = FontStyle.Bold;
                PropertyModification[] prefabMods = PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications(obj);
                foreach (PropertyModification prefabMod in prefabMods)
                {
                    if (prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_Name" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalPosition.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.x" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.y" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.z" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_LocalRotation.w" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_RootOrder" && prefabMod.propertyPath.ToString() != "m_IsActive")
                    {
                        fontColor = prefabModFontColor;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor) fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;
            }
            Rect offsetRect = new Rect(selectionRect.position + offset, selectionRect.size);
            EditorGUI.DrawRect(selectionRect, backgroundColor);
            EditorGUI.LabelField(offsetRect, obj.name, new GUIStyle()
            {
                normal = new GUIStyleState() { textColor = fontColor },
                fontStyle = styleFont
            }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I added the part:

```
if(gameObj.GetComponent<Renderer>() == true)
                {
                    fontColor = Color.yellow;
                }
```

But then in the Hierarchy most of the objects with Mesh Renderer are in black color only some in yellow.

I want to color in yellow all the GameObjects in the Hierarchy with Mesh Renderer or Renderer component. And maybe in red all the gameobjects without Renderer component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the prefabs color is becoming black even if it has renderer because of

> if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor) fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;

maybe try something like this

```
 if (fontColor != prefabModFontColor)
            {
                if(gameObj.GetComponent<Renderer>() == true)
                    fontColor = Color.yellow;
                else
                fontColor = prefabOrgFontColor;
            }
```

Comment: Working. I had to add some more IF/ELSE in other places but it's working. Thanks.